# How to call a function more than once alternately in JS?

Tags: javascript

I will be very grateful if somebody helps me.I am new in JS.I am trying to call a function as many times as my global variable  is.My problem is the function executes simultaneously. How to make it execute alternately? Here is my code:

```
        #general{width:400px;height:400px;margin:0 auto;}
       .cell{width:50%;height:50%;color:black}
       .cell:nth-of-type(1){float:left;background: #81E058}
       .cell:nth-of-type(2){float:right;background: red}
       .cell:nth-of-type(3){float:left;background: blue}
       .cell:nth-of-type(4){float:right;background: yellow}



 <div id='generalwrapper'> 
    <div id='general'>                  
        <div   class='cell' onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>
        <div   class='cell' onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>         
        <div   class='cell'  onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>
        <div   class='cell'   onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>                       
 </div> 
 <div id='buttondiv'>
    <button onclick='startGame()'>On</button>
 </div> 
</div>

       var browser=[];
       var count=1;

        function startGame(){
            for(var i=0;i<count;i++){   
               browserturn();
           }
            count++;
          }

        function browserturn(){
           var x=getNumber();
            var element=x.toString();
             browser.push(element);
            var y=document.getElementById(element);
           y.click();   
          $(y).delay(100).fadeOut().fadeIn('slow');
      }


      function getNumber(){
           var randomNumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * 4)+1);
          return randomNumber;
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "executes simultaneously" and "alternately"?  Do you mean that the fadeOut and fadeIn are happening at the same time for the multiple calls?

Comment: If you are trying to get it to flash (fade out then back in) as many times as the number, then you'll need to change this to a recursive loop instead of a normal for loop.  Is that what you are attempting?

Comment: Yes,exactly,divs change colors not after another but together.

Comment: Ok, thank you for you help.I'll try to use recursive loop though I have no idea what it is but I'll google.

Comment: For you fadeIn you can do an onComplete function which calls the function itself (recursively).  Thus it will wait for the fadeIn before it starts the next fadeOut.   https://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setTimeout` to delay a `recursive` function call. I've written a basic recursive function below:

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var timesToRepeat = 4;


function myRecursiveFunction(count) {
  myDiv.innerText += " ..." + count;
  count++; //increment count 
//this is our exit condition -- otherwise it recurs infinitely!!
  if (count <= timesToRepeat) {
    setTimeout(function() {
//after 600ms, call our function again
      myRecursiveFunction(count);
    }, 600)
  }
}
//our initial call to the function
myRecursiveFunction(1);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi.I am trying to use your code but it doesn't work in my case,though I see it runs here perfectly.What is wrong with my code? can you help me please?Here is my button  to call the function.                                                                 <button onclick='startGame(1)'>On</button>                               function startGame(count){ 
 count++;
 
  if (count <= counter) {
  count++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      startGame(count);
    }, 600)
 
 }
 limit++;
 }

Comment: hard to tell with just this snippet... can you create a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have already solved the problem,thank you very much for your help.:)

Answer (score 1):

you need an interval:

```
var interval;
var limit = 1;
var count = 0;
```

replace startGame for this:

```
    function startGame()
    {
          interval = setInterval(browserturn, 1000);
          limit++;
    }
```

The interval calls your function withi intervals of 1000 miliseconds, and releases the control to the renderer, so you will see the changes

in browserturn you can increment the counter

```
      function browserturn(){
       var x=getNumber();
        var element=x.toString();
         browser.push(element);
        var y=document.getElementById(element);
       y.click();   
      $(y).delay(100).fadeOut().fadeIn('slow');

      // --------------------------------------
      counter++;
      if(counter < limit)
      {
          clearInterval(interval);
          count = 0;
      }
      // --------------------------------------
  }
```

and clear the interval if count is > to limit

Comment: your code does not run simultaneously, but only it allows you to see the changes until it ends

Comment: thank you for your help,I used yur changes but now the changes go endless.what i need is 1 change by first click, 2 changes by second click and so on.

Comment: you need initialize counter = 0 the first time

Comment: And now in changes only once by all clicks :(